# Multiplicative sharing of 1

Tags: secret-sharing

Let R be a ring.

Is there a known/standard way for N parties to perform some exchanges, such that at the end each party holds an element $r_i\in R^\ast$ and $r_1r_2\dots r_N=1$ (and each party $i$ does not know $r_j$ for each $j\neq i$)?

(Or equivalently, share 0 additively?)

Comment: Should party $j\neq i$ know $r_i$? Is there a trusted third party (TTP)? After all if there is a way of holding $N-1$ elements, and there is a TTP, the last party can be given $r_1^{-1}\cdots r_{N-1}^{-1}$ as their share.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this remark. I would like to achieve this in a unital ring (i.e. non UFD) with a (very) large group of units, and without a TTP. I should have stated that, but was hoping for a general answer in a ring R. By the way, in such a ring and using a TTP, your remark certainly is an answer, you should post it as one. Cheers

Comment: And no, parties must remain oblivious of each other's share. Will edit

Comment: [ Share conversion, pseudorandom
secret-sharing and applications to secure computation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.77.8491&rep=rep1&type=pdf) discusses a pseudorandom zero-sharing protocol. A clarifying question, what is your threat model?

Comment: ponchos answer gives a simple construction, but mikaezo's comment points to the real question: What kind of security do you want to achieve? Depending on that, the construction needs to be more complex, e.g. you might want a zero knowledge proof, that parties followed the protocol. In ponchos example, any malicous party can break the construction by using non-inverse elements. And no party will actually be able to detect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ring is multiplicatively commutative, the obvious way to do this is:

- Have each pair $a, b$ create a secure connection, and jointly select two random invertible elements $r_{ab}$ and $r_{ba}$ with $r_{ab}r_{ba} = 1$ (that is, they're inverses of each other).
- Then, $$r_a = \prod_{b \ne a} r_{ab}$$

This is secure (in that any group of parties know nothing about the shares that everyone else has, except the product of their shares), however it does require $O(N^2)$ communication.

If we reduce the requirement to "no single party can deduce anything about any other party, then we can reduce the communication to $O(N)$ (by having $a$ exchange with $a+1$ and $N$ exchange with $1$).